# examine class members in an upper scope in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

have a class method which has a switch/case in it. For representation, something like

```
class class_name {
  int k;
public:
  int method();
  class_name():k(0) {}
};
int class_name::method() {
  k = 2; // class private data member, an integer
  switch(k){ 
    case 0:
      // to examine k at this point 
      // perform path A 
      break;
    case 1: 
      // perform path B 
      break;
  } // switch(k)
  return 0; 
}
```

the question is: if I would like to examine data from an upper scope, like k, from inside the scope of switch/case. Shall I always put a breakpoint somewhere in the upper scope, for instance on the line where the assignment, k=2, is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct z
{
    z() : k(42) {}

    int k;
    int mm ();
};

int z::mm()
{
    int k = 0;
    {
        int k = 1;
        {
            int k = 2;
            printf ("%d\n", k);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    z zp;
    zp.mm();
}
```

When you are stopped on `printf`, it is difficult to print the variables in the outer scopes. `up` doesn't work as it moves between *frames*, not *scopes*. I don't know an easy way but there are workarounds.

`info locals` will print *all* variables local to the function.

```
(gdb) info locals
k = 2
k = 1
k = 0
```

This may be enough for simple integer variables, but what if we had pointers and wanted to dereference them?

```
(gdb) where
#0  z::mm (this=0xbfffec8c) at q.C:18
#1  0x080484a5 in main () at q.C:26
```

OK we're at line 18, what do we know about it?

```
(gdb) info scope 18
Scope for 18:
Symbol k is a variable at frame base reg $ebp offset 8+-28, length 4.
Symbol k is a variable at frame base reg $ebp offset 8+-24, length 4.
Symbol k is a variable at frame base reg $ebp offset 8+-20, length 4.
Symbol this is a variable at frame base reg $esp offset 4+0, length 4.
```

Aha, there are three symbols (whatever that means) named `k`, `$ebp` looks like a register name, and numbers next to it must be offsets.

```
(gdb) p *(int*)($ebp+8-20)
$1 = 0
(gdb) p *(int*)($ebp+8-24)
$2 = 1
(gdb) p *(int*)($ebp+8-28)
$3 = 2
```

Looks like we have a winner here.

Oh, one can always say

```
(gdb) p this->k
$4 = 42
```

Comment: Great answer! I just hope OP was asking for this.

Answer (score 0):

You type up to go 'up'  the call stack. Calling down will do the reverse. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: no, with 'up' , I am out of the class function scope. I would like to somehow stay in the function scope. Basically, if I put a break point where the line 'perform path A' is, I would like examine variables from the local function scope, in this case k...

Comment: What your hypothetical `up-print k` is supposed to do that `up ; print k ; down` doesn't? Would it print `k` from a different scope?

Comment: @izomorphius: OK I think I might know what OP means, see my answer.